# Pressing enter key to close button closes my modal but the event is attached to opener element and reopens the modal

Tags: reactjs, anchor, keydown, keyup, event-propagation

I created a custom modal.
when the modal is closed,
it needs to move focus to the modal opener(focus restoration)

With this code, I can restore the focus and opener element focused OK.

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface ModalContainerProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

class ModalContainer extends Component<ModalContainerProps> {
  nodeFocusedBeforeActivation: HTMLElement | null = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.nodeFocusedBeforeActivation = document.activeElement as HTMLElement;

    setTimeout(() => {
      const firstFocusable = document.getElementById(
        "firstFocusable"
      ) as HTMLElement;
      if (firstFocusable) {
        firstFocusable.focus();
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.nodeFocusedBeforeActivation = document.activeElement as HTMLElement;
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Props) {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return children !== nextProps.children;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log(
      "nodeFocusedBeforeActivation",
      this.nodeFocusedBeforeActivation
    );
    if (this.nodeFocusedBeforeActivation) {
      this.nodeFocusedBeforeActivation.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="modal" className="modal">
        <div id="firstFocusable" tabIndex={0}></div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

interface Props {
  open: boolean;
  children: ReactNode;
}

class Modal extends Component<Props> {
  state = {};

  render() {
    const { open, children } = this.props;
    if (open)
      return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <ModalContainer>{children}</ModalContainer>,
        document.body
      );
    return "";
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

But because the opener is anchor tag it has onKeyUp event listener (for accessibility reasons)

```
<a
        onKeyUp={(e) => {
          console.log("e", e);
          if (e.key === "Enter") e.currentTarget.click();
        }}
        href="/"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setOpen((prev) => !prev);
        }}
      >
        Open Modal
      </a>
```

The problem is when I close the modal with tab and enter key, the key event is also attached to the opener onKeyUp handler and the opener reopens the modal.
So the modal never gets closed. I tried `e.stopPropagation()` but it didn't solve this.

I can't remove the `onKeyUp` event listener, this function is necessary for accessibility purposes.

How can I solve this? I also tested this with the `react-modal` package and it didn't solve the problem.

My custom modal demo in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-forked-m22e5f
react-modal demo in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-vivyxc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: When the modal closes, set some state var to `true` for a couple of milliseconds and then restore it to `false` within a `setTimeout`. execute your `onKeyUp` logic only if this var is `false`. This will prevent your modal from re-opening.

Comment: @k-wasilewski Thank you for your suggestion. However, unfortunately, there are hundreds of anchor element modal openers in our react project.
They all have the onKeyUp event handler. I might look lazy but I'd like to have a chance to resolve this issue without modifying the anchor elements. Because that would be much simpler in my case.

Comment: `onKeyUp={(e) => { if (e.key === "Enter" && !e.defaultPrevented) e.currentTarget.click(); }}`